# Dynamic/Customize message with the entered value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there any way by which i can display the data validation message with the entered value in a cell.

**Example :** A cell which has been restricted to enter the value between 5 to 10, and If i am entering the value as 11, it should display the message saying
"**11** does not come under cell restriction value".

I know we can enter the customize message(cell> Data > Data Validation > Error Alert) but i want the message to show the **current entered value** along with my customized message not only generic message.
and also if possible i want to concatenate any other existing column value of that particular row in future with the error message.

Therefore, can anyone please advice me on the  below queries :

1. How can I display the cell entered value with the message
2. And also another cell value of different column of that specific row.

Thanks !

Comment: Data Validation can't do that because the error message isn't dynamic. Therefore you would need to program a custom validation using VBA.

Comment: thanks Variatus for the reply.I was in the doubt whether its possible from data validation or not. Will implement using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Data Validation, this code will check for changes in a range you define. Then compares the value of the changed cell inside that range against the conditions you set (between 5 and 10 in this case).

Let me know if this works as you need:

*(Copy and paste onto the Sheet where this validation is needed)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B10")) Is Nothing Then 'Change the range as you need
        If Target = "" Then Exit Sub 'If the value is deleted, do nothing
        If Target < 5 Or Target > 10 Then 'Validation condition(s)
            MsgBox Target & " does not come under cell restriction value" 'The message will show the value in the changed cell (Target)
            Target = "" 'Delete the not valid value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also use the following code in the same code sheet to get the changed cell's row, and find another value in the same row and different column:

```
Me.Range("A" & Target.Row)
```